# Word list sought based on corpus of 19th century scientific English

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, corpora

I am currently working on an M.Phil thesis which is focusing on topic modelling 19th century journals.  The journals in question are science, literature and antiquities based.  I have extracted the text using OCR.  I need to build a dictionary of terms with which I can spell check my corpus.  To do this, I need to find a clean scientific corpus or word list that I can build the dictionary from. *edit - English language corpus required (sorry for any ambiguity)*

I have looked at Archer but it's got a lot of OCR errors / non-textual content in the word list.  I have also looked at The Art Corpus, but it is too modern.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: It would help to say which language/s.

Comment: English language only.

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark Davies offers a word list based on the [Historical Corpus of North American English](http://www.ngrams.info/download_coha.asp). The list indicates frequencies for each decade from 1800 to 1990, so you can choose the periods you need. Scientific texts are included in the corpus, but I don't know whether you can get a word list based on specific genres.